# split plot model anova with R

Tags: r, anova

I am trying to solve an exercise with R, that I found in the book **Design of Experiments for Agriculture and the Natural Sciences**(pag. 164)
[image: table]

I have passed the table to the R software

```r
library(tibble)
tb = tibble("replica" = factor(x = rep(1:4,12), labels = c("I","II","III","IV")),
            "row" = factor(x = rep(1:4,c(12,12,12,12)), labels = c("12P","25P","12B","25B")),
            "hybrid" = factor(x = rep(1:2,c(24,24)), labels = c("P3730","B70XH55")),
            "density" = factor(x = c(rep(1:3,c(4,4,4)),rep(1:3,c(4,4,4)), rep(1:3,c(4,4,4)), rep(1:3,c(4,4,4))  ),
                         labels = c("12000","16000","20000")),
            "valor" = c(140,138,130,142,
                        145,146,150,147,
                        150,149,146,150,
                        136,132,134,138,
                        140,134,136,140,
                        145,138,138,142,
                        142,132,128,140,
                        146,136,140,141,
                        148,140,142,140,
                        132,130,136,134,
                        138,132,130,132,
                        140,134,130,136))
```

**but i have difficulty creating aov model**

```r
model = aov(valor ~ replica + hybrid + replica/hybrid + row + replica/row + density + replica/density + row:density ,data = tb)
```

when applying `anova(model)`, it gives me discordant result with the table below

[image]

If there is any other way to apply the model, please I am all ear to your answers. I apply `anova()` for the reason that **I can extract the msres** `anova(model)['Residuals', 'Mean Sq']` and that helps me calculate the **reliability of the model (cv)**

Comment: so one thing you can change is density, it should be a continuous variable, because there's 1 degree of freedom in the final table

Comment: Now for the rest of the variables, you can see this model is over-determined.. meaning some of the coefficients cannot be determined. you can see this by doing ``` model$coefficients```... and in this table, they apparently moved some of the coefficients around

Comment: @StupidWolf hello, interesting, that seemed to me too and is there a way to get the result using some other library? or will it be because of the ANOVA type?

Comment: i had to recheck some old notes..  . The output u need can be obtained using the package agricolae. you can also check http://www.personal.psu.edu/mar36/stat_461/split_plot/split_plot.html and https://www.stat.purdue.edu/~kuczek/stat514/Split%20plot%20example.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the output is obtained using [ssp.plot](https://rdrr.io/cran/agricolae/man/ssp.plot.html) from the `agricolae` library, but first you need to convert the row spacing to a continuous variable:

```
tb$row = as.numeric(gsub("[A-Z]*","",as.character(tb$row)))

library(agricolae)

with(tb,ssp.plot(replica,hybrid,row,density,Y=valor))

ANALYSIS SPLIT-SPLIT PLOT:  valor 
Class level information

hybrid  :  P3730 B70XH55 
row     :  12 25 
density     :  12000 16000 20000 
replica     :  I II III IV 

Number of observations:  48 

Analysis of Variance Table

Response: valor
                   Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
replica             3 237.73   79.24  7.0135 0.0719692 .  
hybrid              1 238.52  238.52 21.1106 0.0193734 *  
Ea                  3  33.90   11.30                      
row                 1 475.02  475.02 71.6262 0.0001487 ***
hybrid:row          1   1.69    1.69  0.2545 0.6319437    
Eb                  6  39.79    6.63                      
density             2 350.04  175.02 19.9233 7.959e-06 ***
density:hybrid      2  37.04   18.52  2.1083 0.1433767    
density:row         2  87.79   43.90  4.9968 0.0153376 *  
density:hybrid:row  2   1.63    0.81  0.0925 0.9119816    
Ec                 24 210.83    8.78                      
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

cv(a) = 2.4 %, cv(b) = 1.9 %, cv(c) = 2.1 %, Mean = 138.8542
```

Comment: oh my God. The agricultural library. Thank you very much @StupidWolf